# Prevent [a-z] from being typed on input type tel on reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an `input type=tel` component that Im trying to give some extra validation and prevent [a-z] from being typed and pasted on the input. So far I've used `e.key` and prop `onKeyDown` which i know I can prevent individual characters but i cant find the way to get [a-z] to work.
Im trying with a good example I found here in SO but Im not sure how to get it, tried adding regEx insted but no luck...

```
const PhoneNumberInput = ({value, onChange, valid, ...rest}) => {

const [phoneValid] = useState(["a", "b", "c"]); <--- I added in a state what I dont want to be inputed, tried with `/[a-z]$*` but I understood that it wouldnt work... 

  return (
    <Input
      className={classNames('form-control ', {
        'is-invalid': !valid,
      })}
      type="tel"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      onKeyDown={e => phoneValid.includes(e.key) && e.preventDefault()}
      valid={valid}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

I've tried adding: `const [phoneValid] = useState(["a-z"]);` but I understood later that prop "onKeyDown" doesnt work that way... How can I do to get the [aA-zZ] blocked from being inputed || && pasted?

UPDATED CODE:

```
const PhoneNumberInput = ({value, onChange, valid, ...rest}) => {
  if(/(^$|^\d*$)/.test(value)) {
     console.log('entered value is number (or nothing i.e. empty input), do something.')
  } else {
    console.log('entered value is not a number - can be alphabet, space, special character, etc' )
  } <------ Im getting both states fired on console independent of number or letter

  return (
    <Input
      className={classNames('form-control ', {
        'is-invalid': !valid,
      })}
      type="tel"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      valid={valid}
      {...rest}
    />
   );
 };
```

Comment: Why do the valid letters need to be in state?

Comment: actually they don't, is the way I found that "work"

Comment: React state is for data that may change during runtime of your application and that requires re-rendering if it does. Your validation criterium is static.

Comment: ok, so actually I could create  function for that and no need to use useState? Im gonna chek it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/(^$|^\d*$)/.test(value)) {
 // entered value is number (or nothing i.e. empty input), do something.
} else {
 // entered value is not a number - can be alphabet, space, special character, etc 
}
```

Comment: ahh this is actually helping me understand! I have the only issue that independent if I input a number or a letter, I get both states logged on console (I just wrote console.log() in front of entered value is number' and 'entered value is not a number ')

Comment: above code should be wrapped inside `onChange` event. Check https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-bird-qo7x0 to get some basic idea

Answer (score 0):

Found a very nice and clean solution:

```
  const PhoneNumberInput = ({value, onChange, valid, ...rest}) => {
  value = value.replace(/[^0-9\+]/g, ''); <--- replace on the value 
  return (
    <Input
      className={classNames('form-control ', {
       'is-invalid': !valid,
      })}
      type="tel"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      valid={valid}
      {...rest}
    />
   );
 };
```